# Find if the first 10 digits of two columns on csv file are matched in bash

Tags: linux, bash, csv, match

I have a file which contains two columns (names.csv), values are separated by comma

```
                   ,                     
a123456789-anything,a123456789-anything
b123456789-anything,b123456789-anything
c123456789-anything,c123456789-anything
d123456789-anything,d123456789-anything
e123456789-anything,e123456789-anything
e123456777-anything,e123456999-anything
```

These columns have values with 10 digits, which are unique identifiers, and some extra junk in the values (-anything).

I want to see if the columns have the prefix matched!

To verify the values on first and second column I use:

```
 cat /home/names.csv | parallel --colsep ',' echo column 1 = {1} column 2 = {2}
```

Which print the values. Because the values are HEX digits, it is cumbersome to verify one by one by only reading. Is there any way to see if the 10 digits of each column pair are exact matches? They might contain special characters!

Expected output (example, but anything that says the columns are matched or not can work):

Matches (including first line):

```
                   ,
a123456789-anything,a123456789-anything
b123456789-anything,b123456789-anything
c123456789-anything,c123456789-anything
d123456789-anything,d123456789-anything
e123456789-anything,e123456789-anything
```

Non-matches

```
e123456777-anything,e123456999-anything
```

Comment: This is probably a good job for `awk`

Comment: For some reason this is not matching only the first 15 digits!

Comment: awk -F, '{if(substr($1, 1, 15) == substr($2, 1, 15)) print}' /home/names.samples seems to work just fine for comma separated files!

Comment: no need for the `RS=","`; what does the following generate: `head -1 /home/names.csv | od -c`? (I'm wondering if you have a Windows/DOS line ending - `\r` - at the end of each line in the file?)

Comment: @markp-fuso
0000000   ,  \n                                                                                                                                                                                                    
0000002

Comment: that's showing the first line as having a single comma and nothing else on the line; if you have other lines in the file that we need to ignore then please update the question with a more representative set of lines from your input file (eg, you should show the first line that appears to have only a single comma)

Comment: @markp-fuso, i'm not sure if that is really relevant because if the first line matches anyway (even if it have less than 15 digits) it should appear  as matched! The code I posted above did work for that case also. I will update it anyway

Comment: your `awk -F, ...` code (in prior comment) does not work for the provided sample as the first field starts with `a1234...` while the 2nd field starts with `<space>a1234...`, so either the provided sample does not match the real data or the `awk -F, ...` code (in the comment) is different from what you're running in your environment ... ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using awk.  It prints every line where the first 10 characters of the first two fields match.

```
% cat /tmp/names.csv                                                                                    
                   ,
a123456789-anything,a123456789-anything
b123456789-anything,b123456789-anything
c123456789-anything,c123456789-anything
d123456789-anything,d123456789-anything
e123456789-anything,e123456789-anything
e123456777-anything,e123456999-anything

% awk -F, 'substr($1,1,10)==substr($2,1,10)' /tmp/names.csv
                   ,                 
a123456789-anything,a123456789-anything
b123456789-anything,b123456789-anything
c123456789-anything,c123456789-anything
d123456789-anything,d123456789-anything
e123456789-anything,e123456789-anything
```